# Dynamic build component with AsyncStorage

Tags: react-native

I am trying to build my sub-component in function _buildComponent, and put result into render(), just have a look at my code below

the problem I met was the AsyncStorage.getItem() is running async, causing it render nothing there in render() method

...react

```
 _buildComponent = async (key) => {
          let val = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key)
            console.log(key + ' : ' +val);
            debugger;//code will run to here after ScrollableTabView finish rendering. but I need to build Arr first.
          if(val == 1) return <PopularView tabLabel={key}>{key}</PopularView>
      }


render() {
            let Arr = Constants.TABS.map(item =
                return this._buildComponent(item).done();
          })

          debugger;//code will run into here directly without waiting building Arr above, making Arr was null when rendering ScrollableTabView

        return (
            <ScrollableTabView
                tabBarBackgroundColor='#2196F3'
                tabBarInactiveTextColor='mintcream'
                tabBarTextStyle={{marginTop:27}}
            initialPage={0}
            renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTabBar/>}
            >

            {Arr}// Arr is null here because the _buildComponent method was not finish yet.
            {/* <PopularView tabLabel='Java'>Java</PopularView>
            <PopularView tabLabel='IOS'>IOS</PopularView>
            <PopularView tabLabel='Android'>Android</PopularView>
            <PopularView tabLabel='Javascript'>Javascript</PopularView> */}
          </ScrollableTabView>
        )
    }
```

...

I have explain my issue in comment, please check it, thanks guys. I do not know what's the best practise to prepare variable before running render().

Comment: You have to put default tabs in State() and when after AsyncStorage execute then update your tabs with new tabs through setState() so it will again render the whole view

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani how should i put tabs into State? I never put a component into a state.

Comment: In your case, your component is same for tabs right? **tabLabel** is dynamic right? I mean you are using same component for every tab is that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution which dynamically add tabs (Updated)

```
_buildComponent = async () => {

    let tabsData = [];

    await AsyncStorage.multiGet(Constants.TABS).then(response => {

            Constants.TABS.forEach((item,index) => 
                {
                    if(response[index][1] == 1) {
                        tabsData.push(response[index][0]); // key
                    }
                }
            );

            // This only render once
            this.setState({ tabLabels: tabsData })
        })
}

componentDidMount() {
   this._buildComponent()
}

render() {
    const tabLabelList = this.state.tabLabels.map((key) => {
        return (
          <PopularView tabLabel={key}>{key}</PopularView>
        )
    })

    return (
        <ScrollableTabView
            tabBarBackgroundColor='#2196F3'
            tabBarInactiveTextColor='mintcream'
            tabBarTextStyle={{marginTop:27}}
        initialPage={0}
        renderTabBar={() => <ScrollableTabBar/>}
        >

        {tabLabelList}

      </ScrollableTabView>
    )
}
```

Comment: Your way actually works, but need to enhanced, I add comment in your code, could you please take a look.thanks

Comment: thanks, it works now. I have updated code a little bit. Personally, RN is not easy to use, many bugs

Comment: Voting up will highly appreciate :-)